# Convert serial date

Tags: r, date

I am having problems with reading excel. A column with dates is being read some cells in serial and others as date as below.

```
date<-c("43942", "43945", "43952", "17/05/2020", "17/05/2020",
        "18/05/2020", "19/05/2020", "18/05/2020", "22/05/2020")
```

How could I convert the vector below to dates? I put it as a string because this is how the column I want to convert looks after reading.

The command

```
as.Date(date, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

return error and

```
as.Date(as.numeric(date), origin = "1899-12-30")
```

convert in NA the non-serial dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this in two steps in any order.

Convert numbers to date

```
new_date <- as.Date(as.numeric(date), origin = "1899-12-30")
```

This will return warnings for dates that cannot be converted to numeric.

Convert remaining dates using `"dmy"` format

```
new_date[is.na(new_date)] <- as.Date(date[is.na(new_date)], "%d/%m/%Y")
#Or using lubridate's dmy
#new_date[is.na(new_date)] <- lubridate::dmy(date[is.na(new_date)])

new_date
#[1] "2020-04-21" "2020-04-24" "2020-05-01" "2020-05-17" "2020-05-17" "2020-05-18"
#[7] "2020-05-19" "2020-05-18" "2020-05-22"
```

Comment: When there are no errors or `NA` in the column of dates the reading is already in the date format `2020-06-05` and applying the `as.Date` makes the date incorrect, for example `4354988-02-24`. How can I do so that I only apply this formatting when necessary? Apply formatting when `is(date) == "POSIXct"` is `FALSE` would be a good solution?

Comment: Do you have multiple date formats? So you say you have "2020-06-05", "18/05/2020" and also numbers like "43942" ?  In such a case, you can look into `parse_date_time` function from `lubridate` which allows you to pass multiple formats.

Comment: I have several excel files and am trying to automate reading them all. There are many typos that cause errors in reading the dates. A non-exhaustive list of wrong entries: 06/05/202, 05/30 or 05/31, 06/052020. When a cell is not in the date format, R converts the others to serial and sometimes the formatting in excel is as serial and R cannot read. The idea would be to read and correct most dates correctly if necessary and the rest to correct later if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grepl` without any warnings

```
i1 <- grepl("^[0-9]+$", date)
newdate <- as.Date(rep(NA, length(date)))
newdate[i1] <- as.Date(as.numeric(date[i1]), origin = "1899-12-30")
newdate[!i1] <- as.Date(date[!i1], "%d/%m/%Y")
newdate
#[1] "2020-04-21" "2020-04-24" "2020-05-01" "2020-05-17" "2020-05-17" 
#[6] "2020-05-18" "2020-05-19" "2020-05-18" "2020-05-22"
```