# Fix date column in excel that imported to R as a mix of integers and character dates

Tags: r, date, import

I am trying to import my excel data sheet and the date column is imported  as a character column with some integer date values mixed in. [image]

Now the class of date column is character.

I am trying to adjust the date column
using

```
Agri$Date <- as.Date(Agri$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

The result is the cells with numbers have NAs and the cells with the dates was adjusted right

Comment: Those look like excel dates. You can try the suggestion in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62185619/convert-serial-date/

Answer (score 4):

The function `convert_to_date()` from the *janitor* package handles mixed date types like that.

For example, with your data:

```
Agri <- data.frame(Date = c("42864", "14/9/2017"))

Agri$Date <- janitor::convert_to_date(Agri$Date, character_fun = lubridate::dmy)

Agri
#>         Date
#> 1 2017-05-09
#> 2 2017-09-14
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(lubridate)
Agri$Date_new<- dmy(Agri$Date)
```

Try by using above library.